# unable to edit document with mongodb update() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am attempting to update my mongodb document with the update() function but find that it does absolutely nothing.

```
// Require mongo db user model
var User = require("./models/user.js");

app.post("/addfriend", function(req, res) {
    // get document by email       
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, doc){

        var requester = req.user;
        var requested = doc;

        User.update(
            { _id: requested._id },
            { $push: { requests: requester._id } }
        )

        return res.redirect("/success");
    });
});
```

This is the user schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,

    friends: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],

    requests: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],

    activityLog: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed],

    events: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed]
});
```

if I log the value of `requester._id` in the console it produces the desired result. If somebody could help debug this code it would be very helpful! Let me know if there is any other code needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to act within the callback. It should if course actually be updating the data, but you are getting to the redirected page before the action actually completes. Also you appear to have a mismatch in where the input is coming from.

There is also no point and it is also not good practice here to "retrieving" the data before performing the update. You already have the "email" field to match, so just do it directly:

```
app.post("/addfriend/:user", function(req, res) {

        console.log( "addfriend: %s", req.params.user );

        User.update(
            { email: req.body.email },
            { $push: { requests: req.params.user } },
            function(err,numAffected) {
                if ( numAffected ) {  // 1 where matched or 0 if not
                   res.redirect("/success");
                } else {
                   // handle not found or possibly error as well
                }
            }                
        );

});
```

Also note that your "user" you want to add is being read from parameters in the URL here, and may need to be adjusted to the POST body if that is where you are sending it in reality. But this would be a general REST type request format.

It is being "logged" here, which is good practice so you can see what you are getting and actions work as intended.

Also consider changing this to a REST API. Redirecting to a page should be other logic related to the general API action which should just return the 200 Ok status 404 Not found or 500 Error as appropriate.

For a bit more improvement on this, also consider to test that the "friend" is not part of the contacts array before you add it. Generally that is a good idea:

```
        User.update(
            { email: req.body.email, requests: { $ne: req.params.user } },
            { $push: { requests: req.params.user } },
            function(err,numAffected) {
               // handling here
            }
        )
```